# Using a batch file to copy multiple files with the same name, and past into new folder with differing names

Tags: batch-file

I have a long list of files that are auto-produced every month.  they'll all have the same file name, with a sequential file extension like this:file.001, file.002, file.003

Each file has differing information, despite having the same name.  What I need to do is copy them from their home directory and paste them into a new directory with names that reflect their purpose, and as text files, like this: Budget.txt, Expense.txt, Retention.txt

Is it possible to do this with a batch file?  I've been unable to find a method that works.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  I've tried that solution, and it works as far as it goes.  the frustrating thing is that the extensions are not always the same, but always sequentially numbered.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Comment: Your question is incomplete. There is not enough data to solve this problem as stated; otherwise, this would be a valid solution: `move file.001 C:\newDirectory\Budget.txt  &  move file.002 C:\newDirectory\Expense.txt  &  move file.003 C:\newDirectory\Retention.txt`